# hydra password penetration test syntax

Tags: penetration-test, brute-force, kali-linux, dictionary, hydra

I am trying to penetrate a password on my own website using hydra.
Let's say that I know login and password and i just put both there like in sample below:

```
hydra -l admin -p password 123.123.123.123 http-form-post "/index.php:userinput=^USER^&passwordinput=^PASS^:password is wrong"
```

After attack like this, hydra says that all the passwords are correct even if i put a wrong one...
I think the last part might be wrong but my website says "password is wrong" when i fail to login. 
So what is the problem then?

EDIT: In addition, when i change

```
:password is wrong
```

into

```
:S=password is correct
```

It this time gives me always falses. No matter if I give a correct one or not.
How do i understand that?

EDIT NEW:  I have logged in on website and added the cookie to the code:

```
:H=Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=cookievalue
```

Comment: @schroeder I actually have read this topic 20 times and It do not help me so I guess thats not a duplicate.

Comment: It all boils down to the server response. You will have to look at the actual syntax of the response, including case.

Comment: @schroeder I am working on it for a week now. I feel so hopeless... How do i check the exact response? Hydra just says I have found a valid password